# In-memory database not persisted across service providers ASP.Net Core 2

Tags: dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, in-memory-database, service-provider

I'm using ASP.Net Core 2 and Entity framework core 2 in my project with In-memory database and I have a call in method where I use:

```
var serviceCollection = DependencyServiceProvider.ServiceProvider;
List<KpiType> types = await serviceCollection.GetService<KpiTypeService().List();
```

Problem is this call returns no Data because Service provider doesn't use already existing *dbcontext* but creates a new one for some reason. Everything works fine with SQL database, but with In-memory one it doesn't, I have tried to find ways how to make it work, but so far I have found only examples for test projects, integration tests etc. I wanna know whether there is a simple solution where I have to simply add some code in *Startup.cs*, since I wanna keep the application code unchanged if possible.

My *Startup cs* has lines like this under *ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)*:

`services.AddDbContext<MyFcDbContext>(x => x.UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "db"));`

`services.AddTransient<KpiTypeService, KpiTypeService>();`

`DependencyServiceProvider.ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();`